# Installing Webistrano on Debian squeeze 64bits

Tags: ruby, debian, gemfile, webistrano

I'm currently trying to install Webistrano on a freshly installed debian squeeze 64bits, but I'm facing some issues that I can't manage to solve.

Note: The machine is created under Xen environment, I don't think this affect the procedure however it seemed important to mention it.

---

**Procedure:**

Informations:

- Ruby version: `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]`
- Rails version: `Rails 2.3.11
- Path modifier with: `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`
- Rails env: development
- Databases have been created
- Databases setups for webistrano are, I believe correct (user/pass/path_to_sock_file)

So, here is what I did:

I first installed the 'basics' packages for such installation:

```
# apt-get install build-essential ruby rubygems libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev libdbd-mysql-ruby mysql-server unzip rake
```

Then I have been downloading and extracting the project into /usr/src. After copying and configuring the files for email/databses setups (as suggested by https://github.com/peritor/webistrano), I continued by installing all the gems needed for the project:

```
bundle install
```

at this point, the command is stuck and isn't doing anything for an hour.

I know it can happen if the Gemfile is complicate, but it doesn't seem to be the case for me. (see the Gemfile following)

```
# cat Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'bundler', "~>1.0.10"
gem "rails", "2.3.11"
gem "mysql"
gem "erubis"
gem "rake"
gem "syntax", "1.0.0"
gem "capistrano", "2.6.0"
gem "open4", "0.9.3"
gem "exception_notification", "2.3.3.0"

group :test do
  gem "mocha", "0.9.8"
end
```

So deciding to go ahead I installed the gems by hands, which once finished gives:

```
# gem list *gems of Gemfile*
bundler (1.0.10)
rails (2.3.11)
mysql (2.8.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
syntax (1.0.0)
capistrano (2.6.0)
open4 (0.9.3)
exception_notification (2.3.3.0)
mocha (0.9.8)
```

So I believe everything should be working without having to run: `bundle install`

This is why I finally tried to create the database's structure with rake:

```
# rake db:migrate --trace
(in /usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b)
rake aborted!
Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`?
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/config/../config/preinitializer.rb:18
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/config/boot.rb:123
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/usr/src/peritor-webistrano-a98ba6b/Rakefile:4
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

According to rake error message, apparently some gems aren't properly installed, which seems weird to be, but I guess he can't find it.

So I double check with bundle tool:

```
# bundle check
Your Gemfile's dependencies could not be satisfied
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
# bundle show
Could not find gem 'mocha (= 0.9.8, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

And I'm stuck here, I just don't know how to continue.
I google around about mocha or gemfile issue, but haven't found much relevant.

I hope everything is clear and easy to understand as this is my first post.

Thanks for any reply/hints, also if I manage to evolve I'll try keeping you up to date!

Answer (score 0):

Check these instructions: 
http://www.gogolek.co.uk/blog/2012/10/web-application-deployment-webistrano-capistrano/

Additionally I had problems with mysql gem installation on my clean debian 6 64-bit, so I had to run

```
$ apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev ruby-dev
```

I ended up with following gems installed

```
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using activesupport (2.3.11) 
Using rack (1.1.6) 
Using actionpack (2.3.11) 
Using actionmailer (2.3.11) 
Using activerecord (2.3.11) 
Using activeresource (2.3.11) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using highline (1.6.20) 
Using net-ssh (2.7.0) 
Using net-scp (1.1.2) 
Using net-sftp (2.1.2) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0) 
Using capistrano (2.6.0) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using exception_notification (2.3.3.0) 
Using mocha (0.9.8) 
Installing mysql (2.9.1) with native extensions 
Installing open4 (0.9.3) 
Installing rails (2.3.11) 
Installing syntax (1.0.0) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```